# Is there any URL where I can download Android SDK updates?

Tags: android, sdk

I been trying hundreds of times to download some updates using the Android SDK manager but I always get the same error:

```
Download Interrupted. Read Time Out.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

My connection seems to be working fine, at least everything else is working fine so I was wondering if there is any other way I can download this updates.

I am referring specifically to Google APIs and SDK platforms for Android 4.4 (API 19)

I tried looking online but could't find any download page so if someone can tip me on how to solve this issue I will really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, http://ady.my/viewer/getting-start.html website may help you. As far as I know, SDK Manager get links from xml files, you should be able to obtain the links for that xml files from the log window of sdk manager. After that, you can manually extract the link for one component from related xml file.

Comment: you can download externally Android SDK components: http://alvarez.tech/descargar-externamente-componentes-android-sdk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I use the Android SDK Manager to update, I have to go to the filesystem and run the manager manually as administrator (right click, run as admin).  Else I will get an error.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! its really strange that the error has nothing to do with permissions.